# CNN training for custom dataset yields a weird result

Tags: pytorch, dataset, conv-neural-network, custom-training

I'm trying to train data (velocity spectrum panel; sgy file) to coordinates (velocity structure profile; csv file) through a simple CNN by PyTorch. In order to test whether the training model is working or not, I tested with 10 data with its labels.

But it yields a weird result of:

> ### Epoch 1
>
> loss:     nan  [    1/   10]
>
> Test Error:
> Accuracy: 0.0%, Avg loss:      nan
>
> ### Epoch 2
>
> loss:     nan  [    1/   10]
> Test Error:
> Accuracy: 0.0%, Avg loss:      nan
>
> ...
>
> ### Epoch 10
>
> loss:     nan  [    1/   10]
> Test Error:
> Accuracy: 0.0%, Avg loss:      nan
>
> Done!

And if I change "batch_size=1" to "batch_size=3", it will show the following error:

> ### Epoch 1
>
> loss:     nan  [    3/   10]
>
> -
>
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-9-3c78b7430da0> in <cell line: 144>()
> 145     print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
> 146     train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
> --> 147     test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
> 148 print("Done!")
>
> <ipython-input-9-3c78b7430da0> in test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
> 135             pred = model(data)
> 136             test_loss += loss_fn(pred, label).item()
> --> 137             correct += (pred.argmax(1) == label).type(torch.float).sum().item()
> 138
> 139     test_loss /= num_batches
>
> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (40) at non-singleton dimension 1

How can I change my code for making the training works? And how to make my code works no matter what number is in "batch_size="?

The data and label is like:

```
print(data)
print(data.shape)
```

> tensor([[[0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000,  ..., 0.0184, 0.0348, 0.0492],
> [0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000,  ..., 0.0442, 0.0363, 0.0250],
> [0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000,  ..., 0.0564, 0.0388, 0.0295],
> ...,
> [1.0000, 0.9606, 0.8394,  ..., 0.0093, 0.0152, 0.0153],
> [1.0000, 0.9524, 0.8419,  ..., 0.0091, 0.0151, 0.0160],
> [1.0000, 0.9305, 0.8363,  ..., 0.0093, 0.0146, 0.0157]]])
> torch.Size([1, 50, 200])

```
print(label)
print(label.shape)
```

> tensor([ 178., 1878.,  822., 1814., 1375., 2162., 1669., 2304., 2065., 2736.,
> 2528., 2780., 2836., 3008., 3396., 3490., 4013., 3518.,   nan,   nan,
> nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
> nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
> dtype=torch.float64)
> torch.Size([40])

The full code would be:

```
# custom dataset  <- revised from "https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html"

import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import pandas as pd
import os
import segyio
import numpy as np

class cvspanel_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.dv_label = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dv_label)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        data_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,
                                 self.dv_label.iloc[idx, 0])
        gth = segyio.open(data_name, ignore_geometry=True)
        data = gth.trace.raw[:]
        data = torch.tensor(data[:, :200])
        data = data.unsqueeze(0)
        arr = self.dv_label.iloc[idx, 1:]
        arr = np.asarray(arr)
        label = arr.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
        label = torch.tensor(label)
        label = label.view([-1, 1])
        label = label.squeeze()

        if self.transform:
            data = self.transform(data)
        if self.transform:
            label = self.transform(label)

        return data, label

train_dataset = cvspanel_dataset(csv_file='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/research_data/synthetic_1D/d-v_label.csv',
                                 root_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/research_data/synthetic_1D/sgy_cvs_panel',
                                 transform=None)

test_dataset = cvspanel_dataset(csv_file='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/research_data/synthetic_1D/d-v_label.csv',
                                 root_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/research_data/synthetic_1D/sgy_cvs_panel',
                                 transform=None)

# dataloader
batch_size = 1

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                           batch_size)
test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset,
                                          batch_size)

# model building

import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=17, stride=1, padding=3),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=10, stride=5, padding=0)
        )
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=6, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=3, padding=1)
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=64*3*13, out_features=512)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=128)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=40)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out1 = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc1(out1)
        out = self.drop(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        out = self.fc3(out)
        return out

# hyperparameter

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = CNN();
model.to(device)

learning_rate = 0.001;

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss();

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate);

# Training  <- revised from "https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/optimization_tutorial.html"

def train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(train_dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    for batch, (data, label) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        pred = model(data)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, label)

        # Backpropagation
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (batch + 1) * len(data)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")


def test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    model.eval()
    size = len(test_dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(test_dataloader)
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, label in test_dataloader:
            pred = model(data)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, label).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == label).type(torch.float).sum().item()

    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")

epochs = 10
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
print("Done!")
```